# Uploading file from heroku to external service with trigger.io/forge

Tags: node.js, heroku, desktop-application, trigger.io

I am trying to upload a file to an external sevice from our trigger.io app deployed to Heroku.

But is seems, that it is impossible to create the request we use on Android and iPhone for uploading the file.

### The request that works looks like this:

```
Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:80
Request URL:http://xxx.xx/umbraco/api/fileupload/post
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview parsed
POST /umbraco/api/fileupload/post HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xx
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 194705
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9xc19ClYRhe1JArC
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: UMB_PANEL=821x877; ASP.NET_SessionId=ae54dmv0uyhzch450xvzpe1a; yourAuthCookie=E84CAA1888280530AB37DCDC59FC7CC90686BB3445C4BA0EEC0F11A13C7CD474A6D33C5AF7
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundary9xc19ClYRhe1JArC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="swimming-elephant1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary9xc19ClYRhe1JArC--
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:38
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 03 Nov 2014 12:02:39 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
X-Robots-Tag:noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet
```

---

The upload will fail unless sent with multipart/form-data, but forge always uses x-www-form-urlencoded, no matter what Content-Type I use.

Here is my upload snippet:

```
var selected_file = document.getElementById('webImg').files[0];
forge.logging.info('triggered get file:' + selected_file);
$ionicLoading.show({duration:1500});
var apiCall = globalApi + 'fileupload/post';
forge.request.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false, 
  contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
  url: apiCall,
  data: [selected_file],
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Uploaded file as '+ eval(unescape(data)).toString());
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.news.ImageUrl = eval(unescape(data)).toString();
    $scope.$apply();
  },
  error: function(error) {
    forge.logging.info('Failed to upload file: '+error.message);
    NewsFactory.checkResponse(error,$scope);
  }
});
```

Is it possible to use multipart/form-data for a forge.request.ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try something like:

```
forge.request.ajax({
    url: some_url,
    files: [file1, file2],
    fileUploadMethod: "multipart",
    success: function (data) {
    },
    progress: function (progress) {
        forge.logging.log("Progress: "+Math.round(100*progress.done/progress.total)+"%");
    }
});
```

Where `file1, file2` is a File object obtained via the `forge.file` API: https://trigger.io/modules/file/current/docs/index.html

Comment: Uploading from iOS and Android works just fine, I do this already like this:

    `forge.request.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiCall,
        files: [file],
        success: function(data) {
          alert('Uploaded file as '+ eval(unescape(data)).toString());
          $scope.news.ImageUrl = eval(unescape(data)).toString();
          $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function(error) {
          forge.logging.info('Failed to upload file: '+error.message);
          NewsFactory.checkResponse(error,$scope);
        }
      });`

Comment: But since i'm on a web-platform (Heroku) I don't have forge.file available, as far as I can tell?